# Cannot add signals to boost::asio::signal_set under Windows

Tags: c++, windows, boost, signals, boost-asio

I'm trying to wait for signals with boost::asio under Windows, but I cannot add the signals. This is what I tried:

```
boost::asio::io_service ioService;
boost::asio::signal_set quitSignals(ioService);
quitSignals.add(CTRL_C_EVENT);
quitSignals.add(CTRL_BREAK_EVENT);
quitSignals.add(CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT);
quitSignals.add(CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT);
quitSignals.add(CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT);
```

This gives a debug assertion for the first one ("Invalid signal or error", 0), and an invalid argument exception for the others. Am I using the wrong signal numbers? The constants I use are defined in wincon.h as follows:

```
#define CTRL_C_EVENT        0
#define CTRL_BREAK_EVENT    1
#define CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT    2
// 3 is reserved!
// 4 is reserved!
#define CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT   5
#define CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT 6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the wrong constants indeed. The constants are the same as under Linux (`SIGINT`, `SIGTERM`, ...) defined in signal.h.

I used the `SetConsoleCtrlHandler` API before (which uses `CTRL_C_EVENT`, ...). That's what got me confused.